# handling multiple events in jquery

Tags: event-handling, telerik, jquery

I have two functions that need to be executed depending on what selection was made in a dropdown list.

For e.g.

if `Dropdownlist1` value is "First" then Disable `Dropdownlist2` and Execute `Function1`
if `Dropdownlist1` value is "Second" then Enable `Dropdownlist2` and Execute `Function2`
if "Third" is selected as `Dropdownlist2` value. I tried a regular if statement in Document ready event but not able to achieve what I want above.

Here is what I have so far:

Form:

```
                 <th>
                    Dropdown List 1
                </th>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("DropDownList1")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "DropDownList1" })
                    .Items(items => {
                        items.Add().Text("").Value("");
                        items.Add().Text("New").Value("First");
                        items.Add().Text("Existing").Value("Second");
                            })%> 
                </td>

                 <th>
                    Dropdown List 2
                </th>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("DropDownList2")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "DropDownList2" })
                    .Items(items => {
                        items.Add().Text("").Value("");
                        items.Add().Text("Three").Value("Three");
                            })%> 
                </td>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
$("#Dropdownlist1").focusout(func1);
});

function func1() {

$("#Dropdownlist1").focusout(function(){
    if($("#Dropdownlist1").val() == "First"){
        $("#Dropdownlist2").attr('disabled','disabled')
        Function1()
    }
    else if ($("#Dropdownlist1").val() == "Second"){
        $("#Dropdownlist2").attr('disabled','')
        $("#Dropdownlist2").focusout(function(){Function2()})
    }
});   

}
```

Comment: It would help if you could post any HTML/Javascript/jQuery code that you've tried.

Comment: @Chase I have updated my question above

Comment: I added an answer below, but if it doesn't answer the question fully then let me know and I'll do what I can to fix it/help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<select id="options">
    <option value=1>option 1</option>
    <option value=2>option 2</option>
    <option value=3>option 3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function func1() { alert('hello from func 1'); };
function func2() { alert('hello from func 2'); };
function func3() { alert('hello from func 3'); };

$('#options').change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
         func1();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
         func2();    
    } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
         func3();
    }
});​
```

Comment: There is a second dropdownlist2 and function2 is only called if "Three" is selected for dropdownlist2 value

Answer (score 0):

If I read the above post correctly, this should do what you've ask for...or at least point you in the right direction.

```
$("#Dropdownlist1").change(function(){
  //if Dropdownlist1 value is "First" then Disable Dropdownlist2 and Execute Function1
  if($(this).val() == "First"){
    $("#Dropdownlist2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    function1();
  }
  //if Dropdownlist1 value is "Second" then Enable Dropdownlist2 and Execute Function2
  else if($(this).val() == "Second"){
    $("#Dropdownlist2").removeAttr("disabled");
    function2();
  }
});

$("#Dropdownlist2").change(function(){
  //and Execute Function2 if "Third" is selected as Dropdownlist2 value
  if($(this).val() == "Third")
    function2();
});
```